# SharedPreferences and ViewPager Unique Key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, key-value

In school we have to develop our first Android app. Android is new to me and I'm here to learn something.

Today I worked the first time with **SharedPreferences** to save information about an ImageButton state. The layout uses a ViewPager. There are 10 items which the user can swipe. The ViewPager contains a TextView that counts the items. That works fine: e.g. the TextView of the first items shows [1/10] and the last one [10/10]. After the TextView you can find an image. That works also pretty good.

Now to my problem: under the Image I have installed an ImageButton. It signals if an item is a favorite or not. Favorite is pictured as red heart and no favorite as grey heart (default ImageResource).

This is my **ViewPager** of the main layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/image_swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="590dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp" />
```

And this is the **pagers layout**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_count"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Here we count..."
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/swipe_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="365dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:onClick="onClickImage" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favourite_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/heart"
    android:onClick="onClickFav" />
```

All items need an **unique key** in order to save every items ImageButton state. The key is composed of the String "fav" and a counter (can be 1-10). That means we have 10 unique keys: fav1 - fav10. When the page is created for the given item position, I try to check if something is stored for the given key.

There can be 2 possible values behind a key: 0 and 1. 0 means no favorite, 1 is a favorite. If there is not yet any key set, the value will be 0 which is the default ImageButton state. After getting the value of the item key, the ImageResource of the ImageButton can be set.

The next step when creating the page, is to save a new key. That key has the name "count" and indicates which item is loaded at this moment.

All I just told you is in this adapter method (**instantiateItem**):

```
     /*
        Create the page for the given position
        Set image resources and text about current position
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_image);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) item_view.findViewById(R.id.favourite_button);

        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText("["+(position+1)+"/10]");

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("favInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        // get the unique key consisting of fav and the current item position
        String key = "fav" + (position+1);

        String value = prefs.getString(key, "0");

        // check if value of favorite key is 0
        // set image resource dependent on what value is set
        if (value.equals("1")) {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
        } else {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        }

        int p = (position+1);
        String count = Integer.toString(p);

        // store index of current adapter item as shared pref
        editor.putString("count", count);
        editor.commit();

        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;
    }
```

So this was when a item is loaded. After that the user can click on the ImageButton which activates following **onClick method** in the main activity:

```
/*
    Method for click actions on the favorite button
    @heart grey heart symbolizes no favorite (flag 0)
    @heart_red red heart symbolizes marked as favorite (flag 1)
*/
public void onClickFav(View v) {
    ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favourite_button);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("favInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // get the count value of the item which is loaded at the moment
    String count = prefs.getString("count", "");

    // get the unique key consisting of fav and the count text
    String key = "fav" + count;

    // get value stored with that key, default: if no value exists take 0
    String value = prefs.getString(key, "0");

    // check if value of favorite key is 0,
    // set image resource dependent on what value is stored behind the key
    if (value.equals("0")) {
        favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
    } else {
        favouriteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    }

    String isFav;

    // switch value to opposite
    if (value.equals("0")) {
        isFav = "1";
    } else {
        isFav = "0";
    }

    // store shared preferences
    editor.putString(key, isFav);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Basically what I do here is: get the current item ("count" key) and build the unique key with it. Then check the value behind it and set the ImageResource accordingly. After that I change the value to opposite and save the unique key.

**My problem:** there happens something, but not the right thing. When the user clicks the ImageButton, the ImageButton of the item before are after it changes. e.g. the user clicks the ImageButton of item 7. Not the ImageButton of item 7 changes, but the ImageButton of item 6 or 8.

Comment: Your problem maybe tied to the fact that you aren't getting any useful information about  button in which page was clicked. You are simply checking that a button was checked. You need to know the "page" on which the button was clicked so you can correctly update the count value inside of the shared preferences. Also I'd recommend loading the SharedPreferences data once and storing it into an array that you update when you need and save it back into the SharedPreferences when the activity gets stopped more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you using **"count"** value in **SharedPreferences** which overrides all the time in adapter so you have to update existing keyvalue so as you say you create key using

```
String key = "fav" + count;
```

but in update you just updating random count

```
// get the count value of the item which is loaded at the moment
    String count = prefs.getString("count", "");
     String key = "fav" + count;
```

so your key mismatches here so do one thing add position as tag for imagebutton as in **instantiateItem**  method add below line

```
// get the unique key consisting of fav and the current item position
        String key = "fav" + (position+1);
    imageButton.setTag(key)
```

now in **onClick**

replace

```
// get the unique key consisting of fav and the count text
    String key = "fav" + count;
```

with

```
// get the unique key consisting of fav and the count text
        String key =v.getTag().toString();
```

you also don't need to find button in **onClick**

replace

```
ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favourite_button);
```

with

```
 ImageButton favouriteButton = (ImageButton)v;
```

because it is already same button's click event and instance

also this sharepreference method only work for fixed image only, for dynamic it will better to use SQLite.

**EDIT**

For sending current position to new activity

In your **instantiateItem** method set

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_image);
 imageView.setTag(postion);//set tag as current position

/*
    Method for click actions on the suggestion image
*/


 public void onClickImage(View v){


        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(activity, DetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra("key_position",Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));///get tag and send it as int extra
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
```

Now in new activity **oncreate**

```
/* onCreate method in new activity (DetailActivity) */ 

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_image);

        Toolbar sToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(sToolbar);




        int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("key_position",0);//get int extra from calling activity

        TextView headline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.island_name);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detailImage);
        TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

        headline.setText(island_name[count]);
        image.setImageResource(image_resources[count]);
        description.setText(description_text[count]);
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you maybe tell me also how I can do it between two activities? If I press the ImageView in one activity, I tried to setTag() for that ImageView with the count. After click another activity starts. In the OnCreate function of the new activity I tried 

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_image);
String tag = imageView.getTag().toString();

...but it gives me a NullPointerException when I try to getTag(). Do you maybe have any idea how to deal with that? 

Thank you sir!

Comment: tag is associated with view in same activity only, please explain what u want to do in another activity ?

Comment: In the other activity I have an TextView. In the OnCreate function I want to load text in the TextView. The text is stored in an array. The array contains 10 Strings but I need to get the String that fits for the ImageView of the main activity. So I need array[count]... Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: do u want to pass some data to another activity?

Comment: do u need count means position of array from previous activity?

Comment: Exactly. I need the position of the last activity in the previous activity in order to chose the right text from the array...

Comment: is this the same method where you set the favourite which is currently in question?

Comment: No. This method is called onClickImage and starts when the User clicks the Image (not the ImageButton) in the View. The method where I set the favouriteButton (=ImageButton) is called onClickFav. Both are in the same activity.

Comment: I'm curious about your idea... Thanks!

Comment: updated check, it an intent communication here u get an explanation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: that's what I needed... 100% Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome you can go through android development tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that instantiateItem () is not called every time you swipe the screen.
Your adapter instantiates each pager layout when the first activity is loaded.
By the way, the main activity expects to call instantiateItem () every time the screen changes.

So, instead of updating count in instantiateItem (), you need to find a method that is called each time the screen is toggled.
For example, you can detect transitions in the pager tab bar and do the following:

```
navigationTabBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            // set "count" this position
        }
    });
```

**P.S**
For efficient processing, it is better to pass the selected screen index directly to the activity rather than using the preference each time the screen is switched.